# How to center smaller unscaled page on A4 page with pdfjam

Tags: pdf, paper-size, scale

I have pages sized 145×205 mm. I can put two-in-one with command:

```
pdfjam file.pdf --nup 2x1 --landscape --twoside \
                --papersize '{205mm,290mm}' --outfile nup.pdf
```

Now I want to put this 290×205 mm page **unscaled** in the center of a landscaped A4 page, that is 297×210 mm. This means there should be unused vertical and horizontal borders 3.5 mm and 2.5 mm respectively.

However whatever I try the page always scales up slightly, with no vertical borders at all and horizontal ones proportionally smaller. Are there some parameters or settings to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, and as soon as I asked I've found the answer. (Works almost everytime.) I need to use *negative* sized trims:

```
pdfjam nup.pdf --trim '-3.5mm -2.5mm -3.5mm -2.5mm' --clip true --landscape \
               --papersize '{210mm,297mm}' --outfile result.pdf
```

Comment: One thing that I do not understand is that --scale 1.0 didn't work.